# How do I disable code analysis while using Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, react-native

I'm building an Android app using React Native. React Native makes use of Gradle to build Android-specific Java code. For some reason, I keep getting the following error when trying to build the project:

```
Note: C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\winescan\Prototype\node_modules\react-native-blur\android\src\main\java\com\cmcewen\blurview\BlurringView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:react-native-blur:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-blur:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not open local class set analysis write cache (C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\winescan\Prototype\android\.gradle\2.14.1\tasks\_react-native-blur_compileReleaseJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis).
   > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\cygwin64\home\james\code\winescan\Prototype\android\.gradle\2.14.1\tasks\_react-native-blur_compileReleaseJavaWithJavac\localClassSetAnalysis\localClassSetAnalysis.lock (Access is denied)
```

The code using a deprecated Java API is provided by a third-party library, so it's not under my control. I would like to have Gradle disable code analysis for these third-party libraries; how can I do that? Thanks.